# SQL Stored Procedure using Merge (Update/Insert) and Group By

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure that I need to add Merge functionality to. I need to Update on Matched rfds_processing_id and Insert when Not Matched. The Group By and Where statements are making it tricky.

**This is the current, working SP**

```
INSERT INTO Summary_Current(model, type, elevation, rfds_processing_id, qty)
  SELECT model, type, elevation, rfds_processing_id, SUM(qty)
    FROM Current_Antenna C
    WHERE C.rfds_processing_id = @rfds_processing_id 
      AND C.model != '' 
      AND C.type IS NOT NULL 
      AND C.elevation IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY C.model, C.type, C.elevation, rfds_processing_id
```

**This is where I am on the Merge**. I'm getting the following error:

```
*Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Procedure CurrentSummary, Line 33 [Batch Start Line 5]
No column name was specified for column 5 of 'SOURCE'.*


MERGE INTO Summary_Current AS TARGET
USING 
  (
  SELECT model, type, elevation, rfds_processing_id, SUM(qty)
  FROM Current_Antenna C
  WHERE C.rfds_processing_id = @rfds_processing_id AND C.type IS NULL AND C.elevation IS NULL
  GROUP BY C.model, C.type, C.elevation, rfds_processing_id  
  ) AS SOURCE
  ON SOURCE.rfds_processing_id = @rfds_processing_id --AND TARGET.rfds_processing_id = @rfds_processing_id
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (model, type, elevation, rfds_processing_id, qty) 
      VALUES (SOURCE.model, SOURCE.type, SOURCE.elevation, SOURCE.rfds_processing_id, SOURCE.qty)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
```

**Updates to Working Merge**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CurrentSummary]
(
    @rfds_processing_id uniqueidentifier = '',
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
MERGE Summary_Current AS TARGET
USING 
  (
  SELECT model, type, elevation, rfds_processing_id, SUM(qty) as total_qty
  FROM Current_Antenna C
  WHERE rfds_processing_id = @rfds_processing_id AND C.model !=''
  GROUP BY C.model, C.type, C.elevation, C.rfds_processing_id  
  ) AS SOURCE
     ON SOURCE.rfds_processing_id = TARGET.rfds_processing_id AND SOURCE.model != ''
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (model, type, elevation, rfds_processing_id, qty) 
        VALUES (SOURCE.model, SOURCE.type, SOURCE.elevation, SOURCE.rfds_processing_id, SOURCE.total_qty) ;
END
```

Comment: Comments like "not working" mean nothing to your reader. Without a better understanding of your schema, a complete script containing your query, and knowledge of the contents of the tables involved we cannot really help. Given your "parameter" and the grouping in your source query, it seems your matching logic is incomplete and a match is always found (and therefore never inserting).

Comment: I think I was a little over-tired when I posted that. I made a change to the Where but still wasn't getting the expected results. It turned out to be some bad data in the source database. I'll update the question with the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't put an alias for your SUM(qty)

Try `sum(qty) as qty` (Although I personally would alias it as total_qty and then adjust the update/insert blocks below)

[image]

This error will always come when you fail to alias a column name in any kind of sub query

Comment: I made the suggested changes and that fixed the error. When I executed the SP it deleted all my rows. So I removed the Delete statement at the end. The insert is not working now.